# Git Plugin not injecting environment variables

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins 2.150.3 and after installing all the suggested plugins I've created a new "pipeline" project.

Just for test I've created a script like the following

```
node {
    stage('Checkout') {
        git branch: 'develop',
            credentialsId: 'myCredentials',
            url: 'https://urlToMyRepo.git'

        sh 'git config --list'
        //sh 'echo `env`'
        echo sh(script: 'env', returnStdout: true)
    }
}
```

In this script, after the checkout (that is completed successfully) I list all the environment variables, but even though I've installed the Git plugin, all its environment variables are not set.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TreeMap from git:

```
gitVar = git(branch: branchName, credentialsId: credential, url: "repository.git")
echo gitVar.GIT_COMMIT
```

Fields:

```
GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL 
GIT_AUTHOR_NAME 
GIT_BRANCH 
GIT_COMMIT
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL 
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME 
GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH 
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT
GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT
GIT_URL
```